# Localization with the Nancy framework

Tags: razor, localization, nancy

I am building an application that will use Nancy as a service with the Razor view engine. This application will have to be be globalized for multiple languages.

I used the demo that I found on Github https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/tree/master/src/Nancy.Demo.Razor.Localization as a starting point. I don't understand why a different view should be required for each language when using resource files. If I need a different view for each language then why bother with resource files and just hard code the different resource strings directly into each view?

I realise that in the HomeModule a route is required for each language but I assumed that the /cultureviewgerman route would just return the CultureView with the German text substituted where the resource string is inserted, however the /cultureviewgerman just returns the German view which kind of defeats the purpose of having resource files.

Am I missing something here?

I appreciate any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It tuns out what I was doing was correct. You can have one view and use resource strings for any view elements that need to be translated. You just need a route for each culture so that you can set the culture on the context. I`m developing this application on Mono and the initial issue turned out to be the resource files not being read so the default text was getting displayed regardless of culture chosen